# Castlerock SNMPc Server constantly shutting down

Tags: snmp

Is anyone here familiar with SNMPc by Castlerock.  I am having an issue where the server keeps failing.  I can restart it, but it shuts down again within 30 seconds of reboot.  Unfortunately, we have no support contract on this box, so im left with no help at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It sounds as if there is a problem with the history log.  While the software is shut down on the server, run histfix.  Histfix.exe has to be ran from a DOS window.